# FileReader with multi Ajax file upload and progress

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a multi-file input field:

`<input type="file" class="image_file" multiple>`

I am using FileReader to show previews of images whilst they are being uploaded.

I now also want to show a progress bar on each individual image whilst it is being uploaded. Here is what I have tried:

```
$('.image_file').change(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var files = this.files;
    var total = files.length;
    var url = input.attr('data-url');

    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var file = files[i];

        formData.append('image_file', file);

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var container = $('.photos .photo:not(.active):first');

            if (container.length) {
                container.css('background-image', 'url(' + e.target.result + ')').addClass('active uploading');
            }
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            xhr: function() {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

                var progressElem = container.find('progress');

                if (myXhr.upload) {
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                        if (e.lengthComputable) {
                            progressElem.attr({
                                value: e.loaded,
                                max: e.total
                            });
                        }
                    }, false);
                }

                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.status == true) {
                    $('.success-message').show();
                }
                else {
                    alert('There was an error uploading your file.);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The issue I am having is on this line in the `xhr` function:

`var progressElem = container.find('progress');`

The image preview appears but the AJAX upload isn't working. No errors are shown in the console either. I think because `var container` was set within the `reader.onload` function, the `xhr` function doesn't have access to it.

If I move that var outside of the function, the image upload works but only one image preview and one progress bar is shown.

Does anybody know the correct way to do this?

Comment: Put that `var container = $('.photos .photo:not(.active):first');` outside the `onload` first, you are not in the same scope, `ajax` cannot retrieve it. Try if it already solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that there is a single xhr that is created and deleted when the for loop runs. The previous xhr are destroyed once the code finishes so it will never run.

The way I got round this was to not use jQuery and/or create a new **xmlhttprequest** for each for loop.

```
var array = []; //ADDED HERE

$('.image_file').change(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var files = this.files;
    var total = files.length;
    var url = input.attr('data-url');

    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var file = files[i];

        formData.append('image_file', file);

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var container = $('.photos .photo:not(.active):first');

            if (container.length) {
                container.css('background-image', 'url(' + e.target.result + ')').addClass('active uploading');
            }
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        array[array.Length] = $.ajax({ //ADDED HERE
            type: 'post',
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            xhr: function() {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

                var progressElem = container.find('progress');

                if (myXhr.upload) {
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                        if (e.lengthComputable) {
                            progressElem.attr({
                                value: e.loaded,
                                max: e.total
                            });
                        }
                    }, false);
                }

                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.status == true) {
                    $('.success-message').show();
                } else {
                    alert('There was an error uploading your file.);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**I need to emphasis that I haven't looked through your code completely but hopefully this will steer you in the right direction.**

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your question description, I assume:

1. **Image Preview works** since you mentioned **"The image preview appears"**
2. **Image uploads** since you mentioned **"If I move that var outside of the function, the image upload works..."**

**Where is the problem then?**

The problem is your variable `container` is not accessible inside `xhr()` function as you mentioned already.

**What is the solution?**

There can be many possible solutions for you problem, but I think moving the ajax request block inside `reader.onload` is better idea since, the variable `container` will be accessible to child function and it will be called only if vaild file is being uploaded.

```js
$('.image_file').change(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  var files = this.files;
  var total = files.length;
  var url = input.attr('data-url');

  for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var file = files[i];
    formData.append('image_file', file);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var container = $('.photos .photo:not(.active):first');
      if (container.length) {
        var ajaxFunction = function() {
          var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

          var progressElem = this.find('progress');

          if (myXhr.upload) {
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
              if (e.lengthComputable) {
                progressElem.attr({
                  value: e.loaded,
                  max: e.total
                });
              }
            }, false);
          }

          return myXhr;
        };
        container.css('background-image', 'url(' + e.target.result + ')').addClass('active uploading');
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: url,
          data: formData,
          cache: false,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          xhr: ajaxFunction.bind(container),
          success: function(result) {
            if (result.status == true) {
              $('.success-message').show();
            } else {
              alert('There was an error uploading your file.');
            }
          }
        });
      }
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
});
```

```css
.photo {
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="image_file" multiple data-url="http://httpbin.org/post">
<div class="photos">
  <div class="photo">
    <progress></progress>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <progress></progress>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated**: used `bind()` function to pass current value of the variable `container` to the `ajaxFunction()`

Comment: You can test the image upload, but remember that the image you upload will be sent to http://httpbin.org/post. Also, for testing only two image preview and two progressbar only supported.